# grepping a particular keyword from python tuple

Tags: python

I have python tuple containing URLS.

**Please refer below:**

```
[(<PysvnList u'http://SVN-URL'>, None), (<PysvnList u'http://SVN-URL/_BRANCH'>, None), (<PysvnList u'http://SVN-URL/_DOCUMENTS'>, None), (<PysvnList u'http://SVN-URL/_DOCUMENTS_2.0'>, None), (<PysvnList u'http://SVN-URL/_TAG'>, None), (<PysvnList u'http://SVN-URL/_TRUNK'>, None)]
```

From this how to get only the _BRANCH, _DOCUMENTS, _DOCUMENTS_2.0, _TAG and _TRUNK and store it as array list.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have tuples with instances of a `pysvlist` object, not string urls.

Answer (score 1):

You need this, as `foo` is the result of the [`pysvn.Client.list()`](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client) method:

```
tags = [i.repos_path[i.repos_path.rfind('/')+1:] for i,z in foo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
import re 
reg = "/(\w+\.?\w+?)>"
#The str() function convert all those objects to strings
unpacked = [str(k) for i in lst for k in i]
matches = [re.findall(reg,i) for i in unpacked if re.findall(reg,i)]

print matches
```

Output:

```
[['_BRANCH'], ['_DOCUMENTS'], ['_DOCUMENTS_2.0'], ['_TAG'], ['_TRUNK']]
```

Comment: You don't *really* think that's text in there, do you?

Comment: No. They're `PysvnList`s.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So this answer is invalid?

Comment: ... I'm not sure. The question is ambiguous, and I'm not sure that even the OP is certain of what they want.

Comment: I'm quite sure this is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

First of all each list within each tuple object needs to be a string otherwise python raises an error.
which would result in the tuple looking something like this.

```
tup = [("http://SVN-URL'>", None), ("http://SVN-URL/_BRANCH'>", None), ("http://svn-ict.mimos.local/svn/mi-trace/_DOCUMENTS'>", None), ("http://SVN-URL/_DOCUMENTS_2.0'>", None), ("http://SVN-URL/_TAG'>", None), ("http://SVN-URL/_TRUNK'>", None)]
newtup = []
item1 = tup[0]
for item in tup:
    if item != item1:
        item = list(item)
        newtup.append(item[0].strip(item1[0]))
```